# R kable_styling disappears to print in html

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I have a markdown file, with table where i want put one row on two in shadow, so i use :

```
kable(DF,"html", caption="graph")%>%
kable_styling(bootstrap_options=c("striped","hover"))
```

on the explorer it's working, but when i want to print it, there is nothing anymore, only the table without shadow to be more readable...

I tried to print in PDF to check but it doesn't work too, i have the error '"url.sty" not found' and i don't arrive to install it manually...  I continue to try for the moment with tuto on internet, because on my work computer i don't have connection internet.

Answer (score 0):

twitter bootstrap theme takes away color from your HTML print by default. In order to render the document in PDF, you'd better have MikTeX installed in full on windows.

---

You can try to use MikTeX's package manager to intall the `url` package in LaTeX. If you have troubles getting specific latex packages to work, I recommend you try out yihui's tinytex package. It's very easy to use. Basically, you can use `tinytex::tlmgr_search()` to search and `tinytex::tlmgr_install()` to install.

Comment: Do you know how can i quit this default mode ?
I have already installed MikTeX to make the PDF, but it missing this url.sty

Comment: @Aurélien Updated my answer